# parametric bootstrap on regression

Tags: r, regression, self-study, bootstrap, nonparametric

I keep trying to perform parametric bootstrap on simple regression analysis to grasp the concept. The internet is full of tutorials on non-parametric one, but I found no explanation or steps concerning parametric bootstrap, so I did it on my own. Since I'm not sure if what was done is o.k., I kindly ask you to correct if I'm wrong (... or praise me if I'm right:) ).

```
library(car)
library(boot)
attach(Anscombe) # I'm going to use Anscombe data

lm.out<-lm(education~income, data=Anscombe) #simple regression to obtain coef.
regre.mle<-coef(lm.out)
```

The model was built, so I was able to get sample $\sigma$ for errors

```
mean(lm.out$resid) # 3.957485e-15
sd(lm.out$resid)   # 34.58725

regre.sim <- function(data, mle){
  n <- dim(data)[1]
  data$education <- mle[2]*data$income+mle[1]+rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=34.58725)
  return(data)
}

regre.stat<- function(data) {
  lm.out<-lm(education~income, data=data)
  return(lm.out$coefficients)
}

boot.out<-boot(Anscombe, statistic=regre.stat, R=100,
               ran.gen=regre.sim,
               sim="parametric", mle=regre.mle)

boot.ci(boot.out, type = "basic", index = 1) #for intercept
boot.ci(boot.out, type = "basic", index = 2) #for beta coef
```

Finally I get this:

```
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 99 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = boot.out, type = "basic", index = 2)

Intervals : 
Level      Basic         
95%   ( 0.0359,  0.0727 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Some basic intervals may be unstable
```

But the question is - this is it (parametric bootstrap on regression)?